# How can I create Sliding Panel by code

Tags: android, layout

```
 final Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams fp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(activity);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateArea = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
dateArea.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(activity);

//SLINDING MENU

final SlidingPaneLayout sp = new SlidingPaneLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams slindlayoutparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        360,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftButtonParam2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

myList = new ListView(this);

ln.addView(myList,linear);
sp.addView(ln,leftButtonParam2);

// Button

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnKnodParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
btnKnodParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
btnKnodParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
btnKnodParam.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 83);
ImageView btnKnod = new ImageView(this);
btnKnod.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

layout.addView(btnKnod, btnKnodParam);

frame.addView(layout, fp);
frame.addView(sp, slindlayoutparam);
addContentView(frame, fp);



sp.setPanelSlideListener(panelListener);
sp.setParallaxDistance(200);

btnKnod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("TEST", "CLICKED");
        if(sp.isOpen()){
            sp.closePane();
        }
        else{
            sp.openPane();

        }
    }
});
```

I want to create a sliding panel that will be opened from left to right by clicking button. My code above works fine, but the problem is it always show the panel from the start and I can't open or close it through button click. Please help me to fix this code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use Googles [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)?
There's an Drawer called `NavigationView` and easily to configure.

[image: NavigationView]

Comment: Because I want to open the menu by button on the screen,not the default button on the Actionbar, and I don't want the Actionbar appears either. ;)